# How to clean child processes on child_process.spawn() in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

The following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
"use strict";

var child_process = require('child_process');

var x = child_process.spawn('sleep', [100],);

throw new Error("failure");
```

spawns a child process and exits without waiting the child process exiting.

How can I wait it? I'd like to call waitpid(2) but child_process seems to have no waitpid(2).

ADDED:

Sorry, what I really want is to kill the child process when the parent exists, instead of wait it.

Comment: if you throw an error the application exits if the error is not catched. You want to wait for the child process and then exit the application?

Comment: In fact, I'd like to kill the child process when the parent process exits.

Answer (score 13):

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
"use strict";

var child_process = require('child_process');

var x = child_process.spawn('sleep', [10]);

x.on('exit', function () {
    throw (new Error("failure"));
});
```

EDIT:

You can listen for the main process by adding a listener to the main `process` like `process.on('exit', function () { x.kill() })`

But throwing an error like this is a problem, you better close the process by `process.exit()`

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
"use strict";

var child_process = require('child_process');

var x = child_process.spawn('sleep', [100]);

process.on('exit', function () {
    x.kill();
});

process.exit(1);
```

Comment: process.on('exit') and process.on('uncaughtException') can do what I want. thanks!

Comment: you actually need to wait for the child process after you killed it, otherwise the child process will turn into a zombie process. When the parent process exits, pid 1 (init) will get the the job of cleaning it up. That works but technically, its better if the parent clean up its own mess before exiting.

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
"use strict";

var child_process = require('child_process');

var x = child_process.spawn('sleep', [10]);

process.on('exit', function() {
  if (x) {
    x.kill();
  }
});
```

Comment: Is `if (x)` a good check if the child process exits before `x.kill()` is called and prevent accidentally killing a process that got a reasigned PID?